# PGP. Sign one element of an XML file, then insert the signature and public key into another element

Tags: python, xml, powershell, gnupg, pgp

I got a task to add a digital signature and the signer's public key to an XML file. The XML file in question would look like this:

```
<data>
<head>
    <field1>foo</field2>
    <fieldn>bar</fieldn>
</head>
<headSigner>John Doe</headSigner>
<signerPublicKey>dfgdgd...sdfgdgdsg</signerPublicKey>
<headSignature>sdafa...sfsafsasdfsafasd</headSignature>
</data>
```

Is this common or even feasible? I can write something in Python or Powershell that would:
1) Write the head XML and dump it to a file.
2) Run gpg to sign the file with the --clear-sign flag.
3) Parse the signed file that gpg makes for the signature string.
4) Add that string to the corresponding element in the XML.

Is there are an easier-or standard-way to do this? Maybe a Python or Powershell module that's already set up for that?

Answer (score -1):

Use C# console app to sign the XML file using a certificate. Like this:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

 using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml ;

    var certStore = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    // get cert rerquired 
    var certificateThumbPrint = "33eeededldodoijdlnkddzippy2e";
    var certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint , certificateThumbPrint, true);
    var myCert = certCollection[0];

    // I can get the correct certificate but the following line throws "Invalid provider type specified." error
    var SigningKey = myCert.GetRSAPrivateKey();

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(args[0] );
    xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
```

Sign file using this:

```
private static void SignXml2(XmlDocument xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 cert , string file1)
{
    // Create a SignedXml object.
    SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

    // Add the key to the SignedXml document.
    signedXml.SigningKey = cert.PrivateKey;

    // Create a reference to be signed.
    Reference reference = new Reference();
    reference.Uri = "";

    // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
    var env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
    reference.AddTransform(env);

    // Include the public key of the certificate in the assertion.
    signedXml.KeyInfo = new KeyInfo();
    signedXml.KeyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert, X509IncludeOption.WholeChain));

    // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
    signedXml.AddReference(reference);

    // Compute the signature.
    signedXml.ComputeSignature();

    // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
    // it to an XmlElement object.
    XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

    // Append the element to the XML document.
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
    xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    xmlDoc.Save(file1);

}
```